# How to Update addTarget method to swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, selector, swift4

when update project code to swift 4 get some error for add.target method
how i can fix this error?

```
 //swift3

var chatLogController: ChatLogController? {
    didSet {
        sendButton.addTarget(chatLogController, action: #selector(ChatLogController.handleSend), for: .touchUpInside)

       uploadImageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: chatLogController, action: #selector(ChatLogController.handleUploadTap)))
    }
}
```

Comment: "get some error" Get _what_ error?

Comment: this error "Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'handleSend()' that is not exposed to Objective-C"

Comment: Well there's your answer. Just read what the error message says! Put `@objc` in front of your `func handleSend...` (which you didn't even _show_ in your question, for heaven's sake).

Comment: but how? i don't use func on this line of code

Comment: No, you use it when you declare it. But, as I said, you didn't show that. Find where you do say `func handleSend` and do what I said to do.

Answer (score 9):

The hint message is telling you what to do, add `@obj` before declaring your function.

```
@objc func handleSend(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer){
    ...
}
```

The reason is because:

> In Objective-C, a selector is a type that refers to the name of an
>   Objective-C method. In Swift, Objective-C selectors are represented by
>   the `Selector` structure, and can be constructed using the `#selector`
>   expression. To create a selector for a method that can be called from
>   Objective-C, pass the name of the method, such as
>   `#selector(MyViewController.tappedButton(_:))`. To construct a selector for a property’s Objective-C getter or setter method, pass the
>   property name prefixed by the `getter:` or `setter:` label, such as
>   `#selector(getter: MyViewController.myButton)`.

Read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID59), at Apples documentation.

Comment: Great answer for those who just starting coding with Swift. People should answer like this more and more less critic :)

Comment: @RoiMulia, thank you.

Comment: @HabibAlejalil, which error and do you use Swift 4?

Comment: But when i use objc get new error : "objc can only be used with members of classes, @objc protocols, and concrete extensions of classes"

Comment: @HabibAlejalil, which Swift version are you running?

Comment: after update to swift 4 , get this error "@objc can only be used with members of classes, @objc protocols, and concrete extensions of classes"

Comment: @RashwanL Swift 4

Comment: @RashwanL thanks . but not working on my project when update to swift 4. link : https://github.com/SombreroElGringo/InnKeeper

Comment: @HabibAlejalil, your project is running fine and the send button works good. Do you run Xcode 9?

Comment: @RashwanL i think xcode 9 have bug!! becuase this project work on xcode 8 but after update to swift 4 get error on xcode 9 and i searching more than 2 days and can't fix this error!!!

Comment: I managed to run the project in Xcode 9 without any problems. Try to clean your project and re-run it.

Comment: @RashwanL you update code to swift 4?!

Comment: No, I did not @HabibAlejalil

Comment: When are they gonna replace #selector with a Swift native?

Comment: Any way to implement without @objc function?

Comment: @JayprakashDubey, no not if you´re using the `selector option.